# Ruby on rails How to remove added columns and insert new columns through a migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

HI I created a Ruby on rails migration file as follows and in the first stage I created tables

then I want to add columns and remove some columns and I modified it as follows

```
class CreateMt940Batches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :mt940_batches do |t|
     t.string :account_number
     t.string :transaction_reference_number
     t.string :information_to_account_owner
     t.string :file_name
     t.binary :raw_data_transaction
     t.string :sha1_checksum
     t.timestamps
   end

   def self.down
     remove_column :account_number, :transaction_reference_number, :information_to_account_owner
   end

   def self.up
     add_column :mt940_batches, :created_by, :updated_by, :integer
   end 
 end
  end
```

but when I ran rake db:migrate nothing has happens. How to accomplish this task . I want to change the model already created as well from this migration file. Um looking a way to do this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add your remove / add column in a separate migration file.

```
class FooMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def down
    remove_column :account_number, :transaction_reference_number, :information_to_account_owner
  end

  def up
    add_column :mt940_batches, :created_by, :updated_by, :integer
  end 
end
```

Please note that your `up` and `down` method should be idem potent. You should be able to go from one to the other when calling `rake db:migrate:down` and `rake db:migrate:up`. This is not the case here.

However here, it seems that you want to achieve 2 different things in a single migration. If you want to add AND remove columns, consider moving each one in a different migration file:

Please read [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration) for more details

You would end up with 2 migrations file like this:

```
class RemoveFieldsFromMt940Batches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :mt940_batches, :account_number, :transaction_reference_number, :information_to_account_owner
  end
end

class AddFieldsToMt940Batches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :mt940_batches, :created_by, :updated_by, :integer
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not edit it if this migration already executed in production env create new one instead 
if not you can use rake db:rollback, rollback migrations

Answer (score 1):

Because this migration is already executed. you have to generate a new migration for adding and removing column in your table, i.e. you want to remove file_name from your table :

run this:

```
rails g migration RemoveFileNameFromCreateMt940Batches file_name:string
```

re-generate that column:

```
rails g migration AddFileNameToCreateMt940Batches file_name:string
```

Than run `rake db:migrate` it will remove column and add column again to your table.

Hope it will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create another migration file with removed column list

```
def change
remove_column :account_number, :transaction_reference_number, :information_to_account_owner
end
```

Create one migration file with added column list

```
def change
add_column :mt940_batches, :created_by, :updated_by, :integer
end
```

Do not alter the create table migration file. Other wise `data saved in the file will be lost.`

If `data lost` is not important for you, then just remove the table using rake `db:migrate:down version=<your migration file version>`

And change the  migration file
then run

```
db:migrate:up version=<your migration file version>
```